# How can I extract using sed or awk between newlines after a specific pattern?

Tags: awk, sed

I like to check if there is other alternatives where I can print using other bash commands to get the range of IPs under #Hiko other than the below sed, tail and head which I actually figured out to get what I needed from my hosts file.
I'm just curious and keen in learning more on bash, hope I could gain more knowledge from the community.
:D

```
$ sed -n '/#Hiko/,/#Pico/p' /etc/hosts | tail -n +3 | head -n -2
```

/etc/hosts

```
#Tito

192.168.1.21
192.168.1.119

#Hiko

192.168.1.243
192.168.1.125
192.168.1.94
192.168.1.24
192.168.1.242

#Pico

192.168.1.23
192.168.1.93
192.168.1.121
```

Answer (score 5):

***1st solution:*** With shown samples could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= '/#Pico/{exit} /#Hiko/{found=1;next} found' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -v RS= '       ##Starting awk program from here.
/#Pico/{           ##Checking condition if line has #Pico then do following.
  exit             ##exiting from program.
}
/#Hiko/{           ##Checking condition if line has #Hiko is present in line.
  found=1          ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found              ##Checking condition if found is SET then print the line.
' Input_file       ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***2nd solution:*** Without using `RS` function try following.

```
awk '/#Pico/{exit} /#Hiko/{found=1;next} NF && found' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** You could look for record `#Hiko` and then could print its next record and come out with shown samples.

```
awk -v RS= '/#Hiko/{found=1;next} found{print;exit}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** These all solutions above check if string `#Hiko` or `#Pico` are present in anywhere in line, in case you want to look exact string then change above only `/#Hiko/` and `/#Pico/` part to `/^#Hiko$/` and `/^#Pico$/` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

With `sed` (checked with `GNU sed`, syntax might differ for other implementations)

```
$ sed -n '/#Hiko/{n; :a n; /^$/q; p; ba}' /etc/hosts
192.168.1.243
192.168.1.125
192.168.1.94
192.168.1.24
192.168.1.242
```

- `-n` turn off automatic printing of pattern space
- `/#Hiko/` if line contains `#Hiko`

  - `n` get next line (assuming there's always an empty line)
  - `:a` label `a`
  - `n` get next line (using `n` will overwrite any previous content in the pattern space, so only single line content is present in this case)
  - `/^$/q` if the current line is empty, quit
  - `p` print the current line
  - `ba` branch to label `a`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```sh
awk -v RS= '/^#Hiko$/{getline;print;exit}' file
awk -v RS= '$0 == "#Hiko"{getline;print;exit}' file
```

Which means:

- `RS=` - make awk read the file paragraph by paragraph
- `/^#Hiko$/` or `'$0 == "#Hiko"` - finds a paragraph that is equal to `#Hiko`
- `{getline;print;exit}` - gets the next paragraph, prints it and exits.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IqTSaO).

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```sh
awk -v RS= 'p && NR == p + 1; $1 == "#Hiko" {p = NR}' /etc/hosts

192.168.1.243
192.168.1.125
192.168.1.94
192.168.1.24
192.168.1.242
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^#/h;G;/^[0-9].*\n#Hiko/P' file
```

Copy the header to the hold buffer.

Append the hold buffer to each line.

If the line begins with a digit and contains the required header, print the first line in the pattern space.